# Issue with Asterisk SIP Trunk: Payload Must Originate from Specific IP in Multi-Cloud Setup

Tags: nat, asterisk, voip

I'm facing an issue with an Asterisk SIP trunk setup involving multiple cloud environments and a Session Border Controller (SBC). Our service provider, Airtel, requires that the SIP payload originates from a specific IP address (192.168.12.12), which is our SBC running Asterisk 16 LTS. However, when connecting another dialer to the SBC (also on Asterisk 16 LTS), Airtel rejects the calls, apparently seeing them as originating from a different IP (10.70.1.15) instead of the required 192.168.12.12. This issue occurs despite NAT configurations and `fromdomain` settings. The setup involves two different Virtual Private Clouds (VPCs).

Cloud 1 VPC for the cloud 1 SBC asterisk configuration

```
[AIRTELSIP]
host=172.68.78.89 ;public is used here 
type=peer
port=5060
canreinvite=yes
context=default
insecure=port,invite
trustrpid=yes
sendrpid=yes
directmedia=no
qualify=yes
fromdomain=192.168.12.12 ;public is used here 
nat=yes
dtmfmode=rfc2833
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
allow=alaw
user=phone

[ASTTEST]
context=externalcalls
host=10.70.1.15 ;public is used here 
type=peer
port=5060
fromdomain=192.168.12.12 ;public is used here 
canreinvite=yes
insecure=port,invite
trustrpid=yes
sendrpid=yes
directmedia=no
qualify=yes
dtmfmode=rfc2833
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
allow=alaw
user=phone

[general]
nat=yes
externip = 192.168.12.12
localnet =10.8.0.5/24
registerattempts=0
registertimeout=60
```

extensions.conf for the cloud 1 SBC asterisk configuration

```
[globals]
[general]
[default]
[externalcalls]
exten => _.,1,NoOp()
exten => _.,n,Dial(SIP/AIRTELSIP/${EXTEN:1})
exten => _.,n,Hangup
```

---

sip.conf The PABX/dialer connecting the dialer  connected to users in cloud 2

```
[SBCTEST]
context=outgoing
host=192.168.12.12
type=peer
port=5060
canreinvite=yes
insecure=port,invite
trustrpid=yes
sendrpid=yes
directmedia=yes
qualify=yes
dtmfmode=rfc2833
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
allow=alaw
user=phone
nat=yes
fromdomain=192.168.12.12

[100]
type=friend
username=100
callerid=100
secret=Ret26#%@$@GHfdg
context=outgoing
host=dynamic
allow=all
nat=yes

[general]
registerattempts=0
registertimeout=60
nat=yes
externip = 192.168.12.12
localnet =10.8.0.5/24
```

extensions.conf The PABX/dialer connecting the dialer  connected to users in cloud 2

```
[outgoing]
exten => _.,1,NoOp()
exten => _.,n,Dial(SIP/SBCTEST/${EXTEN:1})
exten => _.,n,Hangup
```

The Physical diagram illustrating the setup the SBC and PABX , kindly note that they are hosted in different cloud environments

### **Issue:**

Calls originating from Cloud 2 (10.70.1.15) are being rejected by Airtel, as they appear to come from 10.70.1.15 instead of the required 192.168.12.12, despite the **`fromdomain`** and NAT settings.

#### Question:

How can I ensure that all SIP traffic, regardless of its originating cloud environment, appears to Airtel as coming from the required IP (192.168.12.12)? Are there specific configurations or adjustments needed in Asterisk or the network setup to achieve this?

1. **NAT Configuration:** I have configured NAT settings in the Asterisk configuration files with the intention of ensuring that all traffic appears to originate from the IP 192.168.12.12.
2. **`fromdomain` Setting:** In both the SBC and PABX configurations, I've set **`fromdomain=192.168.12.12`** to specify the desired originating IP address.
3. **Directmedia:** I've experimented with enabling and disabling the **`directmedia`** setting, as it controls whether the media stream is sent directly between endpoints.
4. **Network Analysis:** I've conducted network traffic analysis to confirm that the SIP INVITEs are indeed being sent from the correct IP address, but it seems that Airtel is still recognizing the source as 10.70.1.15.
5. **Consulting Documentation:** I've reviewed Asterisk and network configuration documentation to look for any relevant settings or parameters that I might have missed.
6. **Testing with Different Scenarios:** I've tried connecting calls from within the same VPC and from different VPCs to isolate whether the issue is specific to cross-VPC communication.
7. Below is the respsonse I get when I call

   ```
   Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
       -- Called SIP/AIRTELSIP/07042047961
       -- Got SIP response 500 "Server Internal Error" back from 172.68.78.89:5060
       -- SIP/AIRTELSIP-00000e30 is circuit-busy
     == Everyone is busy/congested at this time (1:0/1/0)
   ```

#### Remaining Challenges:

Despite these efforts, the problem persists: Airtel continues to see the calls as originating from 10.70.1.15 instead of 192.168.12.12. I'm looking for insights or suggestions on what else I can try, or if there's a specific aspect of the configuration that I might be overlooking.